# Problems with tokenize

Tags: string, groovy

I have

```
def testStr = 'a:*b*c*d'
```

I want to get

```
tokens[0]=='a'
tokens[1]=='b*c*d'
```

I try

```
def tokens = testStr.tokenize(':*')
```

but get

```
tokens[0]=='a' 
tokens[1]=='b'
tokens[2]=='c'
tokens[3]=='d'
```

How can I do this thing

Comment: Do you mean `tokens[2]=='b*c*d'`?  Or was that supposed to be the result at index `1`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tokenize` takes a list of possible tokens, so it's splitting on both `:` and `*`

You probably want [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) which takes a regular expression to split on (and returns a `String[]`):

```
def testStr = 'a:*b*c*d'

def tokens = testStr.split( /:\*/ )
assert tokens[ 0 ] == 'a'
assert tokens[ 1 ] == 'b*c*d'
```